# Где брать расширения php (php_*.dll)?

Tags: php

Мне нужно расширение php_xmlrpc.dll. В комплекте с php его не было, скачивать с сомнительных сайтов не хочется. В репозитории PECL данное расширение я так же не нашел. Так где его можно найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый надежный вариант - скачать [исходный код](http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/#download) и [собрать его самостоятельно](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) под свою версию php. На linux это практикуется часто, но там делается это проще - парой-тройкой команд в консоли.

Если задача позволяет использовать *nix, можно собрать виртуальную машину (Vagrant + Chef/PuPHPet в помощь), там это расширение можно установить через менеджер пакетов

```
$ sudo yum search php | grep xmlrpc
php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol

$ sudo apt-cache search php | grep xmlrpc
php5-xmlrpc - Модуль XML-RPC для php5
```

Comment: А если работать с Windows?

Comment: @DarkGenius, для случая с Windows я привел ссылки в начале моего сообщения - соберите dll самостоятельно из исходных кодов

Comment: Можно ли скачать библиотеку в уже собранном виде с официального сайта? Возможно, эта библиотека есть в официальной сборке PHP, а сборщики DENWER ее убрали из дистрибутива.

Comment: @DarkGenius, под каждую версию PHP будет своя версия dll. Поэтому если будете скачивать ее отдельно откуда-то, обращайте на это внимание. В [официальных сборках для Windows][1] эта библиотека присутствует (по крайней мере в 5.5)

 [1]: http://windows.php.net/download/